# How to bring the Alexa request handler in another module

Tags: node.js, module, alexa-skills-kit, voice

i am looking for an option how to bring my Alexa request handler in another module. This is my approach:

```
  //index.js
  var Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');
  var tests = require('./secondModule');

  var LaunchRequestHandler = tests('LaunchRequest','Hello, is this working?')

  var skillBuilder = Alexa.SkillBuilders.custom();

  exports.handler = skillBuilder
    .addRequestHandlers(
      LaunchRequestHandler
      )      
    .lambda();
```

and my second module looks like this:

```
//secondModule.js
var Alexa = require('ask-sdk-core');

function Test(requestName, speechText){

    var request = requestName+"Handler"
    console.log("log: " +request)

    request = {
        canHandle(handlerInput) {
            console.log("log: "+request)
            return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === requestName;
        },
        handle(handlerInput) {

            return handlerInput.responseBuilder
                .speak(speechText)
                .reprompt(speechText)
                .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
                .getResponse();
        },
    };

}

module.exports = Test
```

But if i try it like this, the error '"errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'canHandle' of undefined"' comes up. Do you maybe have an idea how i could do it? I am pretty new with Node and JavaScript

here is my package.json:

```
  {
  "name": "hello",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "actions-on-google": "^2.5.0",
    "ask-sdk-core": "^2.0.0",
    "ask-sdk-model": "^1.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: can you share the `dependencies` section in your `package.json` file?

Comment: i just updated my mainpost

Comment: Can you change the versions to latest i.e. `"ask-sdk-core": "^2.3.0"` and `"ask-sdk-model": "^1.9.0"`. Then re-try. Because when i run `node index.js` things are working for me!

Comment: seriously? That is strange, i will try in an hour and tell you again, thank you already!

Comment: for me it says even though i changed the versions: "errorMessage": "Cannot read property 'canHandle' of undefined". And i have exactly the same code like above... Do you have an idea what could be the problem?

Comment: okay it is working when you only do the node index.js but if you try invoke the intent with alexa it does not work..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not returning the `request`. Change your `Test` function to this:

```
function Test(requestName, speechText){

  var request = requestName+"Handler"
  console.log("log: " +request)

  return request = {
    canHandle(handlerInput) {
      console.log("log: "+request)
      return handlerInput.requestEnvelope.request.type === requestName;
    },
    handle(handlerInput) {

      return handlerInput.responseBuilder
            .speak(speechText)
            .reprompt(speechText)
            .withSimpleCard('Hello World', speechText)
            .getResponse();
    },
  };
}
```

This should work now!